# Wordpress: Showing 5 attachments per post

Tags: wordpress, gallery, photo, attachment

I know this may be a simple question but I am a total beginner at Wordpress coding and PHP. I am looking to embed five attachments to each post on my site, so I know it has got to do with inserting something into single.php or loop.php. So let's say I have 8 or 10 photos attached to a post, I want the single post page to show 5 of those photos and have a link to the 'gallery'/attachment.php page. Something like what this website does on this page, the 6 photos at the end of the post entry (http://www.celebuzz.com/2011-05-27/kim-kardashian-kris-humphries-makes-first-post-engagement-public-appearance-photos/)

I have tried using the wordpress [gallery] insert but all it does is show all the pictures and I don't want to use a plugin because I feel that it is overkill and all it needs is some code to call up 5 attached photos. Hope someone can help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try using custom field template plugin
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-template/

Comment: I checked out that plugin at it looks like an overkill and too complex. I want to try to use only code to keep queries and such down

Answer (score 0):

I know you don't want to use plugin. But, for the sake of the questions and I know someone will eventually landed here from search engine.

You can use [attachment](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/attachments/) plugin. This plugin is quite simple and very straightforward.

Once installed, it will add new meta box on post creation page.

You can add as much as images you like and `the loop` part of your template page, you add this snippet:

```
<?php
  if( function_exists( 'attachments_get_attachments' ) )
  {
    $attachments = attachments_get_attachments();
    $total_attachments = count( $attachments ) > 5 : 5 : count( $attachments );
    if( $total_attachments ) : ?>
      <ul>
      <?php for( $i=0; $i<$total_attachments; $i++ ) : ?>
        <li><img src="<?php echo $attachments[$i]['location']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $attachments[$i]['title']; ?>" /></li>
      <?php endfor; ?>
      </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php } ?>
```